# Transform a python dict into string compatible with Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: python, formencode

I'd like to take a python dict object and transform it into its equivalent string if it were to be submitted as html form data.

The dict looks like this:

```
{
   'v_1_name':'v_1_value'
  ,'v_2_name':'v_2_value'
}
```

I believe the form string should look something like this:

```
v_1_name=v_1_value&v_2_name=v_2_value
```

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [urllib.parse.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> urlencode({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
'foo=1&bar=2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterte over the items, join the key and value and create a key/value pair separated by '=' and finally join the pairs by '&'

For Ex...

```
If d={'v_1_name':'v_1_value','v_2_name':'v_2_value','v_3_name':'v_3_value'}
```

Then

```
'&'.join('='.join([k,v]) for k,v in d.iteritems())
```

is

```
'v_2_name=v_2_value&v_1_name=v_1_value&v_3_name=v_3_value'
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2.7, you will encounter this error:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Use [urllib.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) instead.

```
from urllib import urlencode
d = {'v_1_name': 'v_1_value', 'v_2_name': 'v_2_value'}
print urlencode(d)
```

**Output**

```
'v_2_name=v_2_value&v_1_name=v_1_value'
```